# It is possible to integrate turn.js in Angular project with cdn files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I´m working in an Angular project and I want to add the turn.js library to do a flipbook and it is already complete the integration.
[image]

But if I tried to go next page in the book it shows for a few moments the next page but the book goes to his first position like in the picture, also I want to add that in the url go from this http://localhost:4200/#/ to this http://localhost:4200/#/page-1 and then to http://localhost:4200/#/ very fast.

In the console this errors show up:

[image]

And this is the hash.js file:

```
(function() {

'use strict';

var hashes = {},
    regexp = {},
    history = [],
    freq = 100,
    num = 0,
    pushState = false,
    timer = null,
    currentUrl = null,

    freeze = function(obj) {
        if (Object.freeze) return Object.freeze(obj);
        return obj;
    },

    getHashParts = function() {
        return window.location.href.split('#');
    },

    startTimer = function() {
        
        if (!timer)
            timer = setInterval(function() {
                if (num>0 && currentUrl!=window.location.href) {
                    currentUrl = window.location.href;
                    window.Hash.check();
                }
            }, freq);

    },

    stopTimer = function() {

        if (timer) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = null;
        }

    };

window.Hash = freeze({

        pushState: function(yes) {

            if (window.history && window.history.pushState)
                pushState = yes;

            return this;
        },

        fragment: function() {
            
            var hash = getHashParts();
            return (pushState) ?
                window.location.pathname + ((hash[1]) ? '#' + hash[1] : '')
                : hash[1] || '';

        },
        
        get: function(path, params) {
            
            var p, fragment = '', parameters = [];

            for(p in params) {
                if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(p))
                    continue;
                parameters.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[p]));
            }

            if (parameters.length>0)
                parameters = '?' + parameters.join('&');
        
            return (pushState) ? path + parameters :
                getHashParts()[0] + '#' + path + parameters;

        },

        go: function(hash, params) {

            if (this.fragment()!=hash) {
                var to = this.get(hash, params);

                if (pushState)
                    window.history.pushState(null, document.title, to);
                else
                    window.location.href = to;
                }
            
            return this;
        },

        update: function () {
            
            currentUrl = window.location.href;
            return this;

        },

        on: function(hash, callback, title) {

            if (!hashes[hash])
                hashes[hash] = {title: title, listeners: []};
            
            hashes[hash].listeners.push(callback);
            num++;
            startTimer();

            return this;
        },

        check: function() {

            var i,
                hash,
                parts,
                fragment = this.fragment();


            for (hash in hashes) {
                if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(hashes, hash))
                    continue;

                hashes[hash].regexp = hashes[hash].regexp || new RegExp(hash);

                if ((parts = hashes[hash].regexp.exec(fragment))) {
                    if (hashes[hash].title)
                        document.title = hashes[hash].title;

                    for (i = 0; i<hashes[hash].listeners.length; i++)
                        if (hashes[hash].listeners[i].yep)
                            hashes[hash].listeners[i].yep(fragment, parts);
                } else {
                    for (i = 0; i<hashes[hash].listeners.length; i++)
                        if (hashes[hash].listeners[i].nop)
                            hashes[hash].listeners[i].nop(fragment);
                }

            }

            return this;
        }
});

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular needs to have full control of your application.  Do not use jQuery to modify the DOM in any way because Angular will not know about it.

The same goes for Routing.  You obviously have the angular-router installed, and it looks like you're trying to use some non-angular code to modify the route/URL.  That will not work with Angular.

You need to go about this in either a completely Angular way, or do this without Angular at all.  Never mix these concepts